# Web API error in ASP.net only able to perform GET but not PUT POST DELETE

Tags: asp.net

I've started to learn web api to connect my android to mssql and followed this link

http://instinctcoder.com/how-easy-to-start-with-asp-net-web-api-2-0/

Im facing error only able to perform GET but not the other operations..Visual Studio prompts that my "student" is null..tried googling and edit accordingly but still same error.

Below is the screenshot I get when I try to perform PUT/POST on Fiddler

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Maybe you cannot use these two parameters (id and Student) at the same time. Why Student in itself is not enough?

Comment: What does the body of your PUT request look like?

Comment: I will try edit thank you! Btw below is my code for the PUT and POST they were generated once I created the Controller         
https://imgur.com/a/MJNjr

Comment: It prompts error but not on GET method ,attached screenshot below with Fiddler                                                                    https://imgur.com/a/URzLD